# Passing entire class reference via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'd like to pass an entire (custom) class reference to another activity.
This class is called WeekProgramData. WeekProgramData has an array of 7 Day (class) instances and each Day class has several Switch instances.

How can I pass along the class reference between activities, so I can use the methods from that class etc. in other activities?

I already tried the following, but it failed: First, declaration in Activity A

```
WeekProgramData wpd = new WeekProgramData();
```

Code for passing the WeekProgramData class reference in activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), WeekOverview.class);
            intent.putExtra("wpd", wpd);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Code in Activity B for getting the class reference:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    WeekProgramData wpd = extras.getWeekProgramData("wpd");
```

Comment: Have you possibly considered using a database for your application? It seems to me that using a database for this might be a better choice, especially if your data has to stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a class via intent you have to implement the `Parcelable` interface. [Here is a tutorial](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html) on how to do it and it shouldn't take you too long. Once you do this you can pass instances of that class via an intent to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass custom classes between activities is to make your classes [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). This is a way of serializing your data so it can easily be sent around. Once your classes are Parcelable you can use the standard [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) and pass your class in. To retrieve your class you can use [getParcelableExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29). With Parcelable remember you cannot parcel null values and all nested classes must be parcelable as well. In your case you will have to make your WeekProgramData class parcelable as well as your Day and Switch classes.

Answer (score 0):

There could a couple of diiferent ways to do this, but the two best options in my opinion are:

1. `WeekProgramData` should implement `Parcelable`
2. or convert `wpd` into `String` using **Gson**, pass that string to your second activity and finally reconstruct your object from that string using **Gson** again

Comment: I find Parcelable to be yucky, except for IPC and still I would probably used GSON to (de)serialize.  If this communication is within the same process consider [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) and pass the data around that way.

Comment: @BobbyHargett Intents are IPC!

Comment: @Simon, I was talking about Parcelables, which are also used for instance state.